# Axios return nested objects in response verbosely

Tags: javascript, rest, api, axios

I have an axios get request like:

```
axios.get(url + '?hapikey=' + copyFrom)
    .then(res => console.log(res.data));
```

which returns a response similar to:

```
{ name: 'Name',
  anObject: [
      {
          id: 1,
          nestedObject: [Object]
      }
  ]
}
```

How can I get the response of `nestedObject` to show its field/value pairs or is the only way to query it directly in the `.then`?

Comment: You just need to use `res.data.anObject[0].nestedObject`. However, `anObject` is an array, which suggests there may be more than one returned by the api.

Comment: Yes there is this is just a simple example. So the only way would be to query it inside by `get`? There's no way to get the response to automatically show all Objects expanded out

Comment: @VincentNguyen if you only want to print the full object you should take a look into `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Looking more closely, `anObject` is valid. Is it an array or an object? Arrays don't have `key: value` pairs.

Comment: @Mark_M woops, edited

Comment: @J.Pichardo this is the correct answer. Post as an answer if you would like me to green check it

Comment: You can use `console.dir(obj, { depth: null })` to have the console show the whole object.

Comment: @Mark_M this worked perfectly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to deep print an object is to use `JSON.stringify`, something like:

```
axios.get(url + '?hapikey=' + copyFrom)
  .then(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data)));
```

And as @PatrickRoberts commented you could use the optional parameters to pretty print

```
axios.get(url + '?hapikey=' + copyFrom)
  .then(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 2)));
```

Comment: Also use the optional arguments for pretty printing, e.g. `JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 2)` to indent nested structures with 2 spaces.